# Animate surface in SDL/SDL_gfx library

Tags: c, sdl-2

I'm recreating the game 'super hexagon' in c using sdl2 library.

I have drawn the circle in the middle of the application and the little cursor(not the mouse but the triangle around the circle) that is supposed to move around it when the player interact with the keyboard (left and right keys) like so:

```
void Game_run(struct Game *game)
{
    //Previous rendering are cleared.
    SDL_RenderClear(game->renderer);
        //-------------------------------------------------------
        if (filledCircleRGBA(game->renderer,SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2, 10,255, 255, 255, 255) != 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error: the circle was not rendered\n");
            SDL_DestroyRenderer(game->renderer);
        }
        arcRGBA(  game->renderer, SCREEN_WIDTH/2, SCREEN_HEIGHT/2, 100, 0, 80, 255, 255, 255, 255 );
        filledTrigonRGBA (game->renderer, CURSOR_POSITION_X-10, CURSOR_POSITION_Y, CURSOR_POSITION_X+10, CURSOR_POSITION_Y, CURSOR_POSITION_X, CURSOR_POSITION_Y+10, 255, 255, 255, 255);
        SDL_RenderPresent(game->renderer);

        //-------------------------------------------------------
        //We are payng
        game->state = PLAYING;
        SDL_Event event;
        SDL_bool GameRunning = SDL_TRUE;
        while (GameRunning) //while the player didnt loose, the game is running
        {

            while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
            {
                /* code */
                    switch (event.type)
                    {
                    //when a key is pressed
                    case SDL_KEYDOWN:
                                        //Detecting the pressed key
                                        switch (event.key.keysym.sym)
                                        {
                                        case SDLK_LEFT:
                                            printf("Left key pressed\n");
                                            break;
                                        case SDLK_RIGHT:
                                            printf("Right key pressed\n");
                                            break;

                                        default:
                                            break;
                                        }
                        break;
                    //when a key is unpressed
                    case SDL_KEYUP:
                                        switch (event.key.keysym.sym)
                                        {
                                        case SDLK_LEFT:
                                            printf("Left key up\n");
                                            break;
                                        case SDLK_RIGHT:
                                            printf("Right key up\n");
                                            break;

                                        default:
                                            break;
                                        }
                        break;
                    //if the user quit the game
                    case SDL_QUIT:
                        //The game is over
                        GameRunning = SDL_FALSE;
                        game->state = GAME_OVER;
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                    }
            }

        }

}
```

I have already implemented the event listener to detect the user input.
But I have no idea how to animate those elements.

How should I approach the problem? I want to understand how animation works when i render elements using gfx functions..do i need to load the drawn elements into a SDL_Surface first?

Comment: You already animated the mouse cursor. Sure, it doesn't change shape, but it does change position. Animation is just drawing something differently each frame. There are many ways to do it, and there isn't necessarily a best way. Your question is a bit too vague, it would help if you could just try to write the code to draw the things you want, and when you get stuck at something more specific, ask again.

Comment: I'm stuck right now. I have nothing that is animated. All i did is draw a triangle under a circle. i want that triangle to move around that circle.

Comment: Its the first time i use this library. (when i say cursor i talk about the little triangle in the game that moves)

Comment: I think you should try to find a tutorial for SDL_gfx. Once you work through the tutorial you will have a better idea of what you need to do.

Comment: Is it possible to draw something with SDL_gfx and then use it as a spritesheet to animate it? Is this the way to do it?